# How to display commandline operand description in --help output

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I am using Boost.program_options to parse commandlines for my implementation of POSIX utilities. As a simple example, take [`cmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/cmp.html).

Now I would like to have an extra argument `--help` which shows a description of all arguments, which is important in this case. I have:

```
po::options_description options("Options");
options.add_options()("help", "Show this help output.")
                     (",l", "(Lowercase ell.) Write the byte number (decimal) and the differing bytes (octal) for each difference.")
                     (",s", "Write nothing for differing files; return exit status only.")

po::positional_options_description operands;
operands.add("file1", 1);//, "A pathname of the first file to be compared. If file1 is '-', the standard input shall be used.")
operands.add("file2", 1);//, "A pathname of the second file to be compared. If file2 is '-', the standard input shall be used.");

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(options).positional(operands).run(), vm);
po::notify(vm);

if(vm.count("help"))
{
  std::cout << "cmp: compare two files\nUsage: cmp [ -l | -s ] file1 file2\n" << options;
  return 0;
}
```

which is unable to show the `file1` and `file2` options' description. I can of course add them to `options`, but this would add at least two unwanted arguments `[-]-file{1,2}`, which I really do not want. I just want this output for `--help` (without obviously hardcoding it):

```
cmp: compare two files
Usage: cmp [ -l | -s ] file1 file2
Options:
  --help                Show this help output.
  -l                    (Lowercase ell.) Write the byte number (decimal) and the differing bytes (octal) for each difference.
  -s                    Write nothing for differing files; return exit status only.
Operands:
  file1                 A pathname of the first file to be compared. If file1 is '-', the standard input shall be used.
  file2                 A pathname of the second file to be compared. If file2 is '-', the standard input shall be used.
```

Is there any way to achieve this without hacking around the library? I'd think this is pretty basic stuff, but I can't find it in any of the [tutorials](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html).

**UPDATE** For everyone's benefit, I submitted a [feature request](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8430) for this, in a hopefully backwards compatible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not ideal, but how about creating a "dummy" set of program options, let the boost::program_options formatter format its help text for you, and then just remove the dashes with a quick replace?

Then output that help text in addition to the `options` help text.

Something like this:

```
po::options_description dummy_options("Operands");
dummy_options.add_options()
    ("file1", po::value<std::string>(), "A pathname of the first file to be compared. If file1 is '-', the standard input shall be used.")
    ("file2", po::value<std::string>(), "A pathname of the second file to be compared. If file2 is '-', the standard input shall be used.")
    ;

std::stringstream s;
s << dummy_options;
std::string dummy_help_text = s.str();
boost::replace_all(dummy_help_text, "--", "");
boost::replace_all(dummy_help_text, "arg", "     ");

std::cout << dummy_help_text << std::endl;
```

The output looks like this:

```
Operands:
  file1                 A pathname of the first file to be compared. If file1
                        is '-', the standard input shall be used.
  file2                 A pathname of the second file to be compared. If file2
                        is '-', the standard input shall be used.
```

It's not ideal because, among other things, the the spacing between columns will not match the help output from your other `options` output.  But for something quick-and-dirty, that basically works, it could be OK.

It's a thought, anyway.

(I do not see anything in the Boost.Program_Options API that allows you to do this the "right" way, either.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3621947/368896 gives a hint that this sort of thing is not supported, but that is 3 years old now.)

Comment: Bad news, unfortunately `:(`