# Short argument in boost::program_options without long

Tags: c++, boost-program-options

Is it possible to specify an argument with `boost::program_options` with short option only?
The answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621181/short-options-only-in-boostprogram-options) is to use `allow_long_disguise`, which will result in long options being acceptable with a single dash. Is there any way to make some options short-only (single dash and single character), without using `allow_long_disguise`?

Answer (score 0):

No, the library does not support this.